# Unable to load Pig in my new Hadoop installation

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I am executing the following Pig commands:

```
grunt> a = load 'hdfs://localhost:50070/user/data/file2' using PigStorage(',') as (usernames:chararray, passwords:chararray, cost:int);

grunt> dump a;
```

On executing the dump command I get the following error which I am not able to resolve. I am new to bigdata and Apache hadoop stack, I am unable to track this error.

```
2015-12-23 10:06:48,003 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2015-12-23 10:06:48,021 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-12-23 10:06:48,021 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2015-12-23 10:06:48,022 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
2015-12-23 10:06:48,022 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
2015-12-23 10:06:48,024 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2015-12-23 10:06:48,025 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2015-12-23 10:06:48,025 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2015-12-23 10:06:48,039 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-12-23 10:06:48,041 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-12-23 10:06:48,042 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2015-12-23 10:06:48,042 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2015-12-23 10:06:48,042 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - This job cannot be converted run in-process
2015-12-23 10:06:48,093 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/lib/pig/pig-0.14.0/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp111104108/tmp-1319253659/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar
2015-12-23 10:06:48,137 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/lib/pig/pig-0.14.0/lib/automaton-1.11-8.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp111104108/tmp-845511984/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2015-12-23 10:06:48,171 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/lib/pig/pig-0.14.0/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp111104108/tmp-588474917/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2015-12-23 10:06:48,226 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp111104108/tmp1116649992/guava-11.0.2.jar
2015-12-23 10:06:48,270 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/lib/pig/pig-0.14.0/lib/joda-time-2.1.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp111104108/tmp181546662/joda-time-2.1.jar
2015-12-23 10:06:48,277 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2015-12-23 10:06:48,277 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2015-12-23 10:06:48,277 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cacche
2015-12-23 10:06:48,277 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Setting key [pig.schematuple.classes] with classes to deserialize []
2015-12-23 10:06:48,286 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2015-12-23 10:06:48,290 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-12-23 10:06:48,298 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Cleaning up the staging area file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hduse281081215/.staging/job_local281081215_0006
2015-12-23 10:06:48,298 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob - PigLatin:DefaultJobName got an error while submitting 
ENOENT: No such file or directory
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmodImpl(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:652)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:599)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:194)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)
2015-12-23 10:06:48,787 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_local281081215_0006
2015-12-23 10:06:48,787 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases a
2015-12-23 10:06:48,787 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: a[6,4],a[-1,-1] C:  R: 
2015-12-23 10:06:48,791 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2015-12-23 10:06:53,796 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2015-12-23 10:06:53,796 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_local281081215_0006 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2015-12-23 10:06:53,796 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2015-12-23 10:06:53,797 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-12-23 10:06:53,797 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
2015-12-23 10:06:53,797 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2015-12-23 10:06:53,798 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.6.0   0.14.0  hduse   2015-12-23 10:06:48 2015-12-23 10:06:53 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_local281081215_0006 a   MAP_ONLY    Message: ENOENT: No such file or directory
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmodImpl(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:652)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:599)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:194)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)
    hdfs://localhost:54310/tmp/temp111104108/tmp484937622,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://localhost:50070/user/data/file2"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://localhost:54310/tmp/temp111104108/tmp484937622"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_local281081215_0006


2015-12-23 10:06:53,798 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2015-12-23 10:06:53,800 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias a. Backend error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
2015-12-23 10:06:53,800 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - There is no log file to write to.
2015-12-23 10:06:53,800 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias a. Backend error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:925)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:746)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:558)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.getStats(MapReduceLauncher.java:822)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:452)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:280)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1390)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1375)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:1034)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:997)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:910)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.ensureState(Job.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getTaskReports(Job.java:540)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.getTaskReports(HadoopShims.java:235)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.getStats(MapReduceLauncher.java:801)
    ... 20 more
```

Also find the configuration settings.
core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

.bashrc:

```
#HADOOP VARIABLES START
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/ 
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
#HADOOP VARIABLES END


### Pig variables
export PIG_HOME="/usr/lib/pig/pig-0.14.0"
export PIG_CONF_DIR="$PIG_HOME/conf"
export PIG_CLASSPATH="$PIG_CONF_DIR"
export PATH="$PIG_HOME/bin:$PATH"
#PIG VARIABLES END
```

Also my filepath:

```
hduse@vijee-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S510p:/home/vijee$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs:/
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hduse supergroup          0 2015-12-23 10:17 hdfs:///tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - hduse supergroup          0 2015-12-23 09:15 hdfs:///user


hduse@vijee-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S510p:/home/vijee$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs:///user/data
Found 1 items
-rwxrwxrwx   1 hduse supergroup        120 2015-12-23 09:24 hdfs:///user/data/file2
```

Comment: Just from reading the error it seems like the default job name is not set. Unfortunately I can't help you with that. For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Comment: I initially downvoted this for "ASAP", which is rather a demanding tone to use with volunteers. However the question features a good deal of research and is well formatted, so I have cancelled the downvote on this occasion.

Answer (score 0):

I found [another place](https://qnalist.com/questions/4677960/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory) where this question was asked. There the conclusion was this:

> (...) here is a workaround that we found - We replaced the Task
>   Controller from LinuxTaskController to the DefaultTaskController and
>   things are back to normal. Jobs are successful and no more ENOENT
>   messages.